# To which weight is the correction added in a perceptron?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I'm experimenting with single-layer perceptrons, and I think I understand (mostly) everything. However, what I don't understand is to which weights the correction (learning rate*error) should be added. In the examples I've seen it seems arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question.

According to http://intsys.mgt.qub.ac.uk/notes/perceptr.html, "add this correction to any weight for which there was an input". In other words, do not add the correction to weights whose neurons had a value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like you *half* answered your own question: its true you correct all of the non-zero weights, you don't correct all by the same amount.

Instead, you correct the weights in proportion to their incoming activation, so if unit X activated really strongly and unit Y activated just a lil bit, and there was a large error, then the weight going from unit X to the output would be corrected far more than unit Y's weights-to-output.

The technical term for this process is called the delta rule, and its details can be found in its [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_rule). Additionally, if you ever want to upgrade using to multilayer perceptrons (single layer perceptrons are *very* limited in computational power, see [a discussion of Minsky and Papert's argument against using them here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedforward_neural_network#Single-layer_perceptron)), an analogous learning algorithm called back propogation is discussed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation).

Comment: By activation do you mean weight times input?